# Multiple "from" addresses for single Exchange account in Outlook 2007

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, exchange

I have a single Exhange account with multiple aliases (e-mail addresses), for which it recieves incoming mail messages. Using "rules" it is possible to have the incoming messages sorted into folders depending on the address they are sent to.

When composing and sending messages from Outlook, the primary address of the exchange account is used in the "From" header. Without adding additional mail accounts (I really only have one), is it possible to learn Outlook about the alias addresses, making them available as "From" addresses when composing new messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that I know, but there is an alternative.

In the Message window, go to the Options ribbon. In the Fields section, click on Show From.

It will show an additional From field on the Message window and you'll be able to type the originating email address you want. I am quite sure AutoComplete is enabled on this field too, so it'll be easier to select the email addresses after a few times.

[image]